# Help proving the error bound for iterative matrix inversion

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, inverse

> **Theorem:** If $A$ is a convergent matrix ($||A||<1$ for some natural
>   norm) of size $n \times n$, then we have $||B_m-(I-A)^{-1}|| \leq
>  \frac{||A||^{m+1}}{1-||A||}, m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\text{{B}}^\infty_{m=0}$ is an infinite sequence of $n \times n$ matrices that converges to $(I-A)^{-1}$.

I've been looking at this for over an hour and I can't find a good place to start. I tried finding $||B_m-B_{m-1}||$ but got stuck. I'm just not sure how to develop $||A^{m+1}||$ at all.

Comment: The theorem does not make sense as stated, since I don't think it can possibly hold for any sequence $B_m$ converging to $(I - A)^{-1}$. Is there a particular definition of $B_m$ you are considering?

Comment: Did you perchance miss to mention that the $B_m$ are the partial sums of the Neumann series, i.e. the geometric series with matrix powers? Then also the error bound is valid. Else you could define $B_m=\frac{m}{m+1}(I-A)^{-1}$ which does not obey that error bound.